# Modifing gmail contact php Oauth

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-contacts-api

I am trying to modify a contact but doesn't work. The `$idg` value contain the contact info in the way: `ht*t*p://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/xxxxx%40gmail.com/base/yyyyyyyyyyyy`

To include a new contact is working calling: `h*t*tp://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/xxxxx%40gmail.com/full` and using a `$add->setRequestMethod("POST");`
but I am not able to modify a contact.

```
session_start();
$user_email = 'xxxxx%40gmail.com';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("Google Apps PHP Starter Application");
$client->setScopes(array(
     'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/',
     'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/user/',
));


$client->setApplicationName('Pepe');
 $client->setClientId('jjjjjj.apps.googleusercontent.com');
$client->setClientSecret('jjjjjjjj');
$client->setRedirectUri('urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob');
$client->setAccessToken(file_get_contents('refreshtoken.conf'));

    $contact="
    <atom:entry xmlns:atom='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'
        xmlns:gd='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'
        xmlns:gContact='http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008'>
       <atom:category scheme='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind'
        term='http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008#contact'/>
      <gd:name>
     <gd:givenName>".utf8_decode($nom)."</gd:givenName>
     <gd:familyName>".utf8_decode($ape)."</gd:familyName>
     <gd:fullName>".utf8_decode($nom)." ".utf8_decode($ape)."</gd:fullName>
  </gd:name>
  <atom:content type='text'>Notes</atom:content>
  <gd:email rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#home'
    primary='true'
    address='".$ema."' displayName='".utf8_decode($nom)." ".utf8_decode($ape)."'/>
  <gd:phoneNumber rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#mobile'
    primary='true'>
    ".$tel."
  </gd:phoneNumber>
  <gd:structuredPostalAddress
      rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#home'
      primary='true'>
    <gd:city>".$ciu."</gd:city>
    <gd:street>".$dir." ".$num." ".$pue."</gd:street>
    <gd:region></gd:region>
    <gd:postcode></gd:postcode>
    <gd:country>Spain</gd:country>
    <gd:formattedAddress>
      ".$dir." ".$num." ".$pue." ".$ciu."
    </gd:formattedAddress>
  </gd:structuredPostalAddress>
  <gContact:userDefinedField key='Codigo' value='".$cod."'/>
  <gContact:userDefinedField key='Doctor' value='".$doct."'/>
  <gContact:userDefinedField key='Especialista' value='".$espe."'/>
 <gContact:groupMembershipInfo deleted='false'
        href='http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/".$user_email."/base/6'/>
 <gContact:groupMembershipInfo deleted='false'
        href='http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/".$user_email."/base/3adf49fe0beabbb2'/>
</atom:entry>
";


$len = strlen($contact);
$add = new Google_Http_Request("".$idg."");

$add->setRequestMethod("PUT");
$add->setPostBody($contact);

$add->setRequestHeaders(array('content-length' => $len, 'GData-Version'=> '3.0','content-type'=>'application/atom+xml; charset=UTF-8; type=feed'));

$submit = $client->getAuth()->authenticatedRequest($add);
$sub_response = $submit->getResponseBody();

$parsed = simplexml_load_string($sub_response); 
$client_id = explode("base/",$parsed->id);
$idgoogle = $parsed->id;
echo 'The ID of the new entry is: ' . $parsed->id;
echo 'Por ahora es '.  $submit;
  echo 'Entry updated';
 } catch (Exception $e) {
    die('ERROR:' . $e->getMessage());
  }
  }
```

Comment: Check this [page](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/issues/462) and this [one](http://dev.bronto.com/adding-and-updating-contacts-php) for example codes. You can also try testing in [Oauth playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) and see if that actually works or not. Let me know if that's helpful!

Comment: Thanks for your idea. I have checked the links already.

I tried to add 'h*t*tps://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly', in the scope definition but still doesn't work.

Please any idea is welcome.